# Erlang: parsing and summing a list

Tags: erlang

I have been working on how solve an Erlang program that is to perform distributed address spacing. I am trying to create a method that takes an associative and commutative operator, as well a list of values, and then returns the answer by *applying* the operator to the values in the list.

The following two examples represent what the input/output are supposed to look like.

Example 1

```
Input: sum(fun(A,B) -> A+B end, [2,6,7,10,12]

Output: 37
```

Example 2

```
Input: sum(fun (A,B) -> A++B end , ["C", "D", "E"]).

Output: "CDE"
```

This is the code I have so far, which is just a function that adds the elements in a list. How would I change the method to fit the above examples, as well as to produce the correct result? Right now, the code just returns the sum.

```
-module(sum).
-export([sum/1]).

sum(L) -> 
   sum(L, 0).

sum([H|T], Acc) -> 
   sum(T, H + Acc); 

sum([], Acc) ->
   Acc.
```

I wanted to try this serially, before attempting a parallelized version. Please know that before posting this, I tried to look for similar coding examples elsewhere that would help answer my question, but I could not find much, which is why I am posting this.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

sum(Func, Data, Acc) ->
    lists:foldr(Func, Acc, Data).
```

In the shell:

```
13> c(my).                                              
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

14> my:sum(fun(X, Acc) -> X+Acc end, [2,6,7,10,12], 0). 
37

15> my:sum(fun(X, Acc) -> X++Acc end, ["C", "D", "E"], []). 
"CDE"
```

The starting value for the Accumulator(Acc) needs to be different depending on the operator.

Comment: This is great. I compiled the code and it works. Thank you for the help. I also wanted to ask, is there any way to edit the code so that an empty list does not have to be processed at the end?

Comment: @reverb1010, I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but as I said in my answer, `foldr()` requires a starting value to which to *add* things--in the case of a list of numbers, the starting value can be 0 (or 100) and in the case of a list of strings the starting value can be an empty list (or "Hello world").  The way `foldr()` works is that it takes the starting value then *adds* the first value in the list to the starting value, which produces a result, then adds the second value in the list to the result etc., etc.

Comment: I should have clarified my question/comments, or at least tried to. I am new to Erlang, so thanks for the patience. The issue I was thinking through was how to implement the code in an even more serial way and basically divide the work up so that it could be later parallelized without list or foldr methods at all. As it is, when I compile the code and compare the input the example above, I always have to put in a final value into the input for it to work and I now know why this is based on your comments.